# Apply aggregate function to a datatable column and return value, not datatable

Tags: python, py-datatable

Perhaps a dumb question but..

In [R data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table), if I want to get the mean of a column, I can reference a column *vector* like `foo$x` and calculate its mean with something like `mean(foo$x)`.

I can't figure out how to do this operation with [Python datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable). For example,

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import datatable as dt
from datatable import f

# make datatable
np.random.seed(1)
foo = dt.Frame({'x': np.random.randn(10)})

# calculate mean
dt.mean(foo.x)  # error
dt.mean(foo[:, f.x])  # Expr:mean(<Frame [10 rows x 1 col]>) ???
foo[:, dt.mean(f.x)][0, 0]  # -0.0971
```

While the last statement technically works, it seems overly cumbersome as it first returns a 1x1 `datatable` from which I extract the only value. The fundamental issue I'm struggling with is, I don't understand if column *vectors* exists in python datatable and/or how to reference them.

In short, is there a simpler way to calculate the mean of a column with python datable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalizing slightly, let's start with a Frame that has several columns:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from datatable import f, dt
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> foo = dt.Frame(x=np.random.randn(10), y=np.random.randn(10))
>>> foo
            x           y
--  ---------  ----------
 0   1.62435    1.46211  
 1  -0.611756  -2.06014  
 2  -0.528172  -0.322417 
 3  -1.07297   -0.384054 
 4   0.865408   1.13377  
 5  -2.30154   -1.09989  
 6   1.74481   -0.172428 
 7  -0.761207  -0.877858 
 8   0.319039   0.0422137
 9  -0.24937    0.582815 

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

First, the simple `.mean()` method will return a 1x2 Frame with per-column means:

```
>>> foo.mean()
             x          y
--  ----------  ---------
 0  -0.0971409  -0.169588

[1 row x 2 columns]
```

If you want the mean of a single column you have to select that column from `foo` first: `foo[:, f.y]`, or `foo[:, 'y']`, or simply `foo['y']`:

```
>>> foo['y'].mean()
            y
--  ---------
 0  -0.169588

[1 row x 1 column]
```

Now, if you want to have a number instead of a 1x1 frame, you can either use the `[0, 0]` selector, or call function `.mean1()` instead:

```
>>> foo['y'].mean()[0, 0]
-0.1695883821153589

>>> foo['y'].mean1()
-0.1695883821153589
```